# Вывод по порядку pandas, dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

- есть датафрейм с набором столбцов (например: 4,2,3,1)
  df
- есть список названий столбцов, которые необходимы (например: 3,1,4) именно такой порядок
  columns=[3,1,4]

Вопрос: как применить df[columns], чтобы вывод производился именно по порядку аналогичному таблице - 4,3,1?

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
print(df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(cols)])
```

Пример:

```
In [105]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)), columns=[4,2,3,1])

In [106]: df
Out[106]:
   4  2  3  1
0  3  8  7  7
1  7  7  4  7
2  7  5  9  8

In [107]: cols = [3,1,4]

In [108]: df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(cols)]
Out[108]:
   4  3  1
0  3  7  7
1  7  4  7
2  7  9  8
```

Comment: Я, кажется, понял - задача немного в другом )

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, исправил )

Comment: Воу, у них встроенный `intersection` есть, кажется, создатели `pandas` всё, что только можно зафигачили, опять же не знал )

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, так (инициализацию `df` я скопировал у MaxU, уважаемого):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)), columns=[4,2,3,1])
columns=[3,1,4]
show_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col in columns]
df[show_columns]
```

Содержимое `df[show_columns]`:

```
    4   3   1
0   0   5   8
1   5   5   7
2   2   0   9
```

Я перебираю столбцы именно в том порядке, в котором они присутствуют в `df`, при этом оставляю только те из них, которые есть и в `columns`. Списковые сокращения - очень удобный инструмент для таких вещей.

Кстати, получается, что порядок следования столбцов в `columns` вообще не важен, непонятно, зачем вы делаете на порядке акцент. Так что если число столбцов будет большое, лучше превратить `columns` во множество, так будет быстрее работать (остальной код при этом не меняется):

```
columns=set([3,1,4])
```